# Wix detect .NET 4.5.2 in bundle

Tags: wix, windows-installer, .net-framework-version, wix-extension

I am trying to make an installer bundle for .NET 4.5.2.

I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513664/how-to-install-net-4-5-with-a-wix-bundle) instructions, and it works fine for that .NET version.

But when I change the version, as below, it does not detect the installed .NET version when I run the installer for the second time:

```
  <ExePackage Id="Netfx452" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
    SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)Resources\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
    DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.5.51209&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.5.51209&quot;))"
    InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0) AND (NOT (Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.5.51209&quot; OR Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.5.51209&quot;))"/>
```

Comment: You could modify the WiX NetFxExtension for 4.5.1. Here's the source: https://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx451.wxs

Comment: The link is not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is only supported in WiX 3.9:

1. Include a reference to WixNetFxExtension.dll

   [image]
2. In your Bundle.wxs file, add the following to your `<Bundle><Chain>` element

   ```
   <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Redist" />
   ```

   Alternatively, substitute any of the following for the `Id` attribute's value:

   ```
   PackageGroup ID     Description
   NetFx452Web         .Net Framework 4.5.2 web setup.
   NetFx452Redist      .Net Framework 4.5.2 standalone setup.
   ```

Here is a short example of final markup:

```
<Bundle Name="My App" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Me" UpgradeCode="{YOUR-GUID-HERE}">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>
    <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Redist" />
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.AppInstaller.TargetPath)" />
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: Let's say then the MsiPackage requires the existence of .NET v4.5.2 to install (because it starts up a service or something).  How can I set this to force a reboot after v4.5.2 installs and then resumes upon restart?  I see references to some older .NET version detection stuff but I  assume there's a better/easier way to do this with WiX v3.9 and up.